# Angular Material input not showing value when not focused

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, material-design, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material 1.0.3 and `<input>` elements are correctly set but their values are visible if I click one to focus it. Once it's not focused I can't see the value.

The markup is as follows:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Some label</label>
    <input ng-model="model.someProperty">
</md-input-container>
```

After checking if it's a CSS issue, I've found that the following CSS selector is turning `color` into `transparent`:

```
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus) {
     color: transparent;
}
```

And obviously, it seems like the input doesn't have the `.md-input-has-value` CSS class.

For now, I can't figure out what's going wrong.

#### Additional info

In my case, in opposite of Angular Material demos, controllers are on directives and UI Router states.

**In fact, I can confirm that I've already copy-pasted the same markup in my `index.html` as direct child of `<body>` and then it works as expected.**

Maybe it has some relation with this open issue: [Compiling material directives on the fly: md-input-has-value attribute not set #3017](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3017).

#### `<md-input-container>` has the `md-input-has-value` CSS class

I've also checked that `<md-input-container>` has the `md-input-has-value` CSS class.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? From these 4 row, its hard to say whats wrong.

Comment: Can you share a codepen or plunkr demo? Have you modified the default theme and implemented any custom palette?

Comment: Could you provide the full code? (including the angular controller, the html where your controller is defined etc..)

Comment: @RayonDabre Ugh, I believe that it would be hard to get the code to work in a CodePen/Plunkr because I'm developing a SPA using ES2015+, JSPM, SystemJS, Babel..........

Comment: Actually the issue is reproduced when I don't bind the input to the controller

Comment: @Chirac It's not a small Angular app, it would be hard to reproduce it online just for this part of the code

Comment: You can check my update where I've found that's a CSS issue

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, It would be harder to debug this without reproducing it. It works well here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Comment: @RayonDabre I know it works in demos. Every day I try to use 10% of my time to overcome this issue and I don't find why it's actually happening

Comment: @RayonDabre There's a "small" difference between the demos and my case: controllers are configured in UI Router states, or the controller is the one provided in a directive. Maybe there's a bug with this use case, who knows

Comment: @RayonDabre Check my last update.

Comment: Can not help you without know what is happening!

Comment: @RayonDabre I've added an answer which doesn't solve the issue at all, but finally, the problem is Chrome!

Comment: @RayonDabre I use SO everyday and I know that we tend to request a "working code sample", but not all issues are solved with samples :D

Comment: But at least, there must some way to debug the issue :)

Comment: @RayonDabre Argh, finally Chrome has still issues. When the inputs are part of a directive, I still experience the issue, while inputs in views *as is* are working correctly. And other browsers work flawlessly...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer did you ever find a solution? Just ran into the same issue and also found that it was because of the :not(md-input-has-value) running the color: transparent even though the parent object (md-input-container) has the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular material version - v1.0.1-master-edfe2ad

Just subscribed to help put anyone who is having this issue.

Go to the angular-material.css file and change this  (for my is line 11,334)

```
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus),
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field,
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field,
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-millisecond-field,
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field,
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-second-field,
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-week-field,
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field,
md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
color: transparent; }
```

to color black and viola fixed....

Answer (score 5):

This issue may also occur when you nest `md-input-container` like this:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Some label</label>
        <input ng-model="model.someProperty">
    </md-input-container>
</md-input-container>
```

I just had to remove this extra `md-input-container` and problem solved.

---

Explanation (given by **Segev -CJ- Shmueli**):

> When you add a value it adds class="md-input-has-value" to the
> wrapping md-input-container. If your input is wrapped by yet another
> one it, it will not receive that class and as a subsequence the text
> will become transparent.

Comment: Explanation: When you add a value it adds class="md-input-has-value" to the wrapping md-input-container. If your input is wrapped by yet another one it, it will not receive that class and as a subsequence the text will become transparent

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did something I should did a week ago: **try the same app on other Web browsers**.

Exactly the same code in Firefox, Internet Explorer 11 and Edge works as expected: it doesn't suffer the issue explained in my question.

The joke here is a simple snippet doesn't demonstrate the issue, because with this simple markup Chrome 47 returns 0 nodes when querying the selector using `document.querySelectorAll`. In my actual markup, it finds the whole element.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = "elements found: " + document.querySelectorAll("md-input-container:not(.md-input-has-value) input:not(:focus)").length;
});
```

```html
<md-input-container class="md-input-has-value">
  <label>Some label</label>
  <input ng-model="model.someProperty">
</md-input-container>

<div id="result"></div>
```

### Update

I've updated Chrome to 48 and the problem has been solved. After all, it's a browser-specific issue with `:not` selector when the elements are very nested. If someone can find an open/closed issue in Chrome's issue tracker it would be great in order to add a link in my answer.

### Update 2

Argh! Now some `<input>` fields work well and others are still experiencing the issue. They're the ones that are inside directives.

In Firefox, Explorer and Edge still works everything.

Comment: If you haven't already, you should definitely post this as a bug on our issue tracker (http://github.com/angular/material/issues) so that we can investigate.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. Inputs inside the directivies are still affected by the issue... :(

Answer (score 0):

I was working on some input fields and faced the same issue. Please check your code and make sure you're not using input container inside another input container like

```
<md-input-container class="md-input-has-value">
   <label>Some label</label>
   <input ng-model="model.propertyName">
</md-input-container>
```